# Какие типы данных и в каком виде можно передавать через TCP bsd socket?

Tags: c++, c, сокет, tcp

Во всех примерах использования bsd сокетов на си для передачи и приема информации используется массив символов фиксированной длинны `char buff[255]`. Например `read(socketFD, buff, sizeof(buff));`. Возникает пара вопросов:

1. Обязательно ли использовать массив char, или же можно передавать произвольные объекты? например можно ли передать `double buff[255]` или даже `struct someStructType buff[255]`?
2. Что будет, если отправить массив например в 200 элементов, а на принимающей стороне считать только 100? При повторном чтении мы прочитаем те же элементы, или же следующие 100 элементов?

Comment: Передаются байты и ничего кроме байтов. Как вы будете переводить "любой тип" в байты и обратно - зависит от вас. Сможете перевести - сможете передать.

Comment: 2) Что будет, если из бочки на 200 литров вылить 100, закрыть кран и снова открыть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В сокет передаются исключительно байты, что бы ваши объекты превратить в байты или создать их из них нужно использовать протоколы сериализации, такие как например T-L-V или ProtoBuf.
В примерах приводится массив-буфер для считывания в него информации, как правило функция чтения возвращает реальное количество считанных байт. Если вы  отправите 200 байт, а считаете 100, то вам надо будет считать потом еще 100.
Буфер может быть любого размера (но как правило его делают не более MTU/MRU). Как правило при обмене данными через сеть, они упаковываются в пакет вида: `packetLength:packetData`, что позволяет гарантированно считывать переданный пакет. Так, например, отправляя 200 байт нужной информации вы:

1. Считываете в буфер приема данные из сокета.
2. Читаете из этого буфера длину пакета `packetLenght` (сколько байт - зависит от типа переменной и архетиктруры);
3. Создаете буфер размером `packetLength`. Это не тот же самый буфер в который вы читаете из сокета!!
4. Копируете из буфера приема данные в созданный буфер, при этом если размер данных меньше, чем осталось в буфере, то копируете нужно кол-во, если больше, то пишите все, а затем дочитываете далее из сокета в буфер приема до тех пор, пока не вытащите все.

Answer (score 3):

Первый, по сути, вопрос переносимости. Вы просто передаете блок байтов. Нужны гарантии корректной интерпретации их с другой стороны. Вдруг там другой порядок байтов? Другой формат данных? Или еще что-то? Вот поэтому и используется максимально обобщенный вариант - просто сколько-то байтов. Что касается структур - то учтите еще и выравнивание. Надеюсь, чем чревата передача просто объектов в духе

```
string s;
write(fd, &s, sizeof(s));
```

вы понимаете? :) А то некоторые ухитряются...

Второй - прочтете при следующем чтении остальные 100 байтов. Если, конечно, до того не закроете соединение :)